# SQL - Cannot add check constraint without checking the existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, alter-table

I need to modify an existing constraint. I read on multiple topic that it's impossible, we need to delete and recreate it. So I've delete it and rewrote it. When trying to save it in SQL Server Management studio I got this error message :

> Unable to add constraint chk_AnneeNaissance. The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK CONSTRAINT chk_AnneeNaissance.

I know that I have some row in my database not fulfilling this constraints but I want to add it for the next insert.
I've looked around and I found that I need to do the command myself with a NOCHECK so I'm trying this command :

```
ALTER TABLE [GENERAL].[dbo].[Base] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT chk_AnneeNaissance
```

But I have this error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'chk_AnneeNaissance'.

Can someone help me writing the right command?

Comment: MySQL and sql server are two different products. Pls tag your questions with the relevant tags only.

Comment: please try to change your constraint name chk_AnneeNaissance and see if works, if yes, then you properly contain chk_AnneeNaissance somewhere

Comment: which CONSTRAINT are you tried to add ?

Comment: I'm trying to add chk_AnneeNaissance

Comment: Where's the code for the actual constraint? It's check constraint? You're missing the actual code for the check it should do

Comment: check this one may be you will get the idea. read it carefully  https://sqlwithmanoj.com/tag/alter-table-with-nocheck-add-constraint-references/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [ERI_COPY_20170315].[dbo].[Base] WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_AnneeNaissance
CHECK (
[Année de naissance] IS NOT NULL AND 
[Année de naissance]>=([Date de valeur]-(80)) AND 
[Année de naissance]<=([Date de valeur]-(15)) AND
len([Année de naissance])=(4)
)
```

It works perfectly. Thanks James Z ! I didn't know where I should put my constraints code.